# Algolia search delayed job ArgumentError: job cannot be created for non-persisted record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job, algolia

I'm using the algoliasearch-rails [gem](https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-rails) and trying to set up callbacks to be async. I'm using delayed job (`gem 'delayed_job_active_record'`).

config/application.rb

```
config.active_job.queue_adapter = :delayed_job
```

patient_profile.rb

```
  algoliasearch :per_environment => true, id: :uuid, enqueue: :trigger_delayed_job do
    attribute :first_name, :last_name, :name, :photo_url
    geoloc :latitude, :longitude
    attributesToIndex ['first_name', 'last_name', 'name']
  end

  def self.trigger_delayed_job(record, remove)
    if remove
      record.delay.remove_from_index!
    else
      record.delay.index!
    end
  end
```

However, when deleting a job I am not able to put the job onto the queue because of the following error: `ArgumentError: job cannot be created for non-persisted record`. The record has already been deleted from the table before the callback is triggered. If I throw in a debugger and look at the logs you can see that there is a `DELETE` called before `trigger_delayed_job` gets called. 
`SQL (0.2ms)  DELETE FROM "patient_profiles" WHERE "patient_profiles"."id" = $1  [["id", 1]]`

My question is, how can I get delayed job to play nicely with algolia here so `trigger_delayed_job` is called before `DELETE`? Or am I missing something else here?

My rails version is 4.2.6

Comment: Just for future viewers: a discussion is happening [on GitHub about this issue](https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-rails/issues/75).